# How does this cakephp scaffold know to display the name and not the primary key id?

Tags: cakephp, has-many, scaffolding, belongs-to, model-associations

I am new to cakephp and just created a basic blog using scaffolding.  There are two models: User and Post. When the posts are listed, it lists the user's name, which is not the primary key.  I am not sure why it is listing the user's name.  I want to make it list the primary key of the user.  How do I do this?  I apologize if this question is basic, but I cannot find an answer to it.

Here are the models:

```
class User extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array('Post');
}

class Post extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

Here are the controllers:

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
    public $scaffold;
}

class PostsController extends AppController{
    public $scaffold;
}
```

This might be helpful.  Here is the users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cakephp_blog`.`users` (
  `id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR( 150 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR( 60 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR( 60 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield) you'll see that cake is assuming that any field called `name` or `title` will be used as the displayField (99% of use cases).

If you want to display the primary key you can set:

```
public $displayField = 'id';
```

in your model.